# Как сделать если фокус пропадает элемент становился прежним?

Tags: javascript

```js
let a = document.querySelector('.a');
a.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(a.tagName = 'DIV'){
    console.log(true);
    a.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<textarea>');
    a.remove();
  } 
 
});

 a.onblur = function(){
  a.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<div></div>');
  a.remove();
}
```

```css
.a{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
textarea{
  border: 3px solid blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

Создайте `<div>`, который превращается в `<textarea>`, если на него кликнуть.

`<textarea>` позволяет редактировать HTML в элементе `<div>`.

Когда пользователь нажимает Enter или переводит фокус, `<textarea>` превращается обратно в `<div>`, и его содержимое становится HTML-кодом в `<div>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let a = document.querySelector('.a');
let t = document.querySelector('textarea.b');
a.addEventListener('click', () => {
  t.classList.remove("hide");
  a.classList.add("hide");
  t.focus();
});

t.onblur = function(){
  t.classList.add("hide");
  a.classList.remove("hide");
}
```

```css
.a{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

textarea{
  border: 3px solid blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<textarea class="b hide"></textarea>
```